# Looping through all HTML elements in Java (Selenium testing)

Tags: java, html, loops, selenium

I'm trying to keep a count of a certain HTML element, and I want to loop through every element on the page and increment this count whenever the HTML element is detected. What would my loop condition be?

Comment: Please show some code if you can

Comment: As Saifur mentioned, please show us what you have tried, and also examples of the HTML element you are attempting to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a loop at all to achieve this, create a list of all WebElements matching your locator. Then print the size of this list.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(<YOURLOCATOR>);
System.out.println(elements.size());
```